# Creating a TCP Server to host ELF files

Tags: c, bash, docker, network-programming, elf

I've setup a TCP server with docker for a CTF competition I'm going to be hosting. The problem is, when I nc (netcat) into the running TCP Server on my localhost machine, the client does not receive the output of the executable.

I've never setup a TCP Server in the past, so this is new to me.

Bash Script

```
#!/bin/sh -e

exec tcpserver -v -P -R -H -l 0 0.0.0.0 1337 ./buff
```

Short C Script

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FLAG ""

int main() {
    int safe = 0xFACE0FF;
    char name[32] = "";
    fprintf(stderr, "So you wanna take my flag? ");
    read(0, name, 0x32);
    if (safe == 0xdec0de) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Here's my flag: %s", FLAG);
    } else {
        puts("Goodluck dude!");
    }
}
```

I want the client to read and send input. From the above C script.

The above bash script creates a successful TCP Server and listens for any incoming connections on port 1337, however when the client connects to the TCP Server, they can only pass input.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html). The read function will wait until it's read the given number of bytes - in your case you specify `0x32` bytes (which is probably not what you expect). That's why it seems like it doesn't put output - it's waiting for 50 input characters before it continues.

You might want to consider [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or something similar instead.

Also, check to make sure you use the same base on variable declaration as buffer sizes.